# Let $v,\,w,\,x,\,y\in \mathbb{Z}_{\,+}$ such that $v+ w+ x+ y= vw- xy\,.$ Prove $v+ x$ is a composite number.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Let $v,\,w,\,x,\,y\in \mathbb{Z}_{\,+}$ such that $v+ w+ x+ y= vw- xy\,.$ Prove $v+ x$ is a composite number.

I solved above by using the following equality, I hope to see a nicer one(s) more, thanks a real lot!

$$0< v+ x= \frac{y(\,v+ x\,)+ v+ x}{y+ 1}= \frac{y(\,v+ x\,)+ vw- xy- w- y}{y+ 1}= \frac{(\,v- 1\,)(\,w+ y\,)}{y+ 1}$$

Thus, $v+ x$ is a composite number and because

$$\because\,(\,v- 1\,)(\,w+ y\,)- y- 1= (\,v- 2\,)(\,w+ y\,)+ w- 1\geqq 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is false: $x=1,y=2,w=3,v=4$. $$1+2+3+4=3\cdot4-1\cdot2$$ but $1+4=5$ is not composite.

Comment: I lastly realized my mistake, $(\,v- 1\,)(\,w+ y\,)- y- 1= (\,v- 2\,)(\,w+ y\,)+ w- 1\geqq 0$ isn't enough ! Thanks !